# java 8 grouping by with distinct count

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping, collectors

```
SELECT Count(1) AS total,
          'hello' AS filter,
          field1 AS field1,
          Count(DISTINCT field2) AS total_field2
   FROM table
   WHERE field = true
     AND status = 'ok'
      GROUP  BY field1
```

Doubts how to make a map using java8 to store the following result. Map key must be field `field1` and map value must be `total_field2` field.

That is, I need to group my list using field field1 and count field field2

**For the total field I have**

```
myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1, Collectors.counting())) 
// this is just counting the records grouped by field1
```

My result is correct **total_field1: {4=55, 6=31}**

For field2, I needed something like this, but it's just giving me a record

```
myList.stream().filter(distinctByKey(MyObject::getField2))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1, Collectors.counting()));

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
```

Result **total_Field2: {4=31}**

should return me 2 example records **total_Field2: {4=31, 6=31}**

**Example** @Naman

```
public static <T, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> filtering(
        Predicate<? super T> predicate, Collector<? super T, A, R> downstream) {

        BiConsumer<A, ? super T> accumulator = downstream.accumulator();
        return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
            (r, t) -> { if(predicate.test(t)) accumulator.accept(r, t); },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
    }

myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1, filtering(distinctByKey(MyObject::getField2), Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: please remember [ask]

Comment: If i understand you want to group by on `field1` and distinct count of `field2` is that right ?

Comment: @Deadpool, that's what I want to accomplish and I'm not getting

Comment: @JoSSte sorry i'll improve a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate to [Deadpool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357523/1746118) is to count `distinctByKey` after groupingBy `field1` while mapping to entries and then finally collecting to a `Map` as:

```
Map<String, Long> r = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream().filter(distinctByKey(MyObject::getField2)).count()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

---

If you were on Java-9 or above, you could have used `Collectors.filtering` as a `downstream` with the `Predicate` defined using the utility `distinctByKey` such as :

```
Map<String, Long> result = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1,
                Collectors.filtering(distinctByKey(MyObject::getField2),
                        Collectors.counting())));
```

---

**Note**: The above two approaches are quite different though, the former groups all the list items by one field (`field1`) and then within each subgroup finds a distinct count by another specific field(`field2`).

On the other hand, the latter groups all the distinct items by the key(`field2`) and then groups these by another key(`field1`) with counting reduction.

Comment: worked bringing two records but one reset {4=31, 6=0} 
the six should come with 31

Comment: @EdeGerSil Yes, my bad. The `Collectors.filtering`, filters the object from the source as the actual collection and is almost same as using `filter(distinctByKey(MyObject::getField2))` here.

Comment: Sorry @Naman I did not understand the solution.

I made according to the example that left reference to java8

I inserted in my question the coding I made if it can help

Answer (score 7):

Actually i used `Set` to eliminate the duplicates and `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to get size

```
Map<String, Integer> res =  list.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getField1, 
                                        Collectors.mapping(MyObject::getField2, 
                                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), set->set.size()))));
```

As per suggestion by @Naman you can also use method reference `Set::size`

```
Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Set::size))));
```

Comment: ..further `Set::size` for `set->set.size()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myList.stream().map(obj -> Pair.of(obj.getField1(), obj.getField2()))
      .distinct()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getLeft, counting()));
```